Wife is missing, husband suspected of murder
A woman is found missing, her last diary pages say that she's afraid of her own husband with words "he just might kill me" or something like that. Her husband is suspected of murder.
Later on it appears that she faked her own murder, left somewhere else, waiting for news about her missing to spread. She gets robbed, finds her old friend who was in love with her, but he locks her in his rich appartment. Then she kills while having sex with him and goes back to her husband.
After all, they appear in an interview where he needs to assure her of his love despite knowing what she did, and not release this knowledge to public.

I have to assume you are referring to Gone Girl (2014), the recent movie with Ben Affleck and Rosamund Pike.
The plot follows your question almost to a T, including also an elaborate framing of the husband by her surreptitious purchasing of leisure and luxury goods to make it appear that he was in financial trouble and a fake pregnancy.
It is based on the novel of the same name.  
